# Hibernate SaveOrUpdate using GeneratedValue for primary key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and I am trying to learn the nuances of it .
I am trying to saveOrUpdate an entity using hibernate . 
My pojo class :-

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TestDB")
    public class TestCaseData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private intid;
    @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String location;
    private String name;

    /*Getters and setters*/
```

Main Class :-

```
    public TestDbDao{
        public static void main(String args[]){
           TestCaseData d1 = new TestCaseData();
           TestCaseData d2 = new TestCaseData();
           TestCaseData d3 = new TestCaseData();

           d1.setHash("New York");
           d1.setName("Panache");
           saveOrUpdate(d1);
           /** d2 and d3 **/
    }
  }
```

I `saveOrUpdate` this entity .The first time I  run the main class ,3 rows are created in the table.
When I run the same program the second time , according to my knowledge when there  is saveOrUpdate, it should either save if the value is not present in the table or update if the already existing value is updated in the table.But I find same 3 rows being added to the table with different ids.
ids 1,2,3,4,5,6 are same . Why doesnt saveOrUpdate doesnt work with generateValue id ?
Can anyone please explain ?

Comment: Did you got any exception?

Comment: No I did not get any exception .Directly same d1,d2 and d3 were added to the table with new ids 4,5,6

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is expected, because you are running the program 2 times.

Each time the program run, Hibernate only see you passing in 3 new entities (without ID), therefore you are telling Hibernate to create new records in DB.

To see the effect of saveAndUpdate(), you may pass a detached instance to Hibernate in 2nd time, e.g. a `TestCaseData` instance with ID corresponds to an existing record in DB, but with different `name`.  You should be able to see Hibernate updating the corresponding record in DB.

Comment: Just got another downvote.  I am keen on knowing the reason :)